# Why is this happening? What is the recommended fix? Python 'for' loop iteration failure

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, for-loop, generator, index-error

## Python 2.7 win32 crashing on 'for' loop header, IndexError

All for loops are refusing to break (Python 2.7.13) on win32
      - only on execution of '.py' file
an example would be:
`for x in range(5): #Line 1 of main.py
    print x        #Line 2 of main.py`

and the resulting error would be:
    `File "pathToFile\main.py", line 1, in <module>
        for x in range(5):
IndexError: array index out of range`
I also have 32-bit python 3.6 installed, but the default for opening '.py' files is python 2.7
This error happens on custom made generators too, but never in the interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know what exactly is causing this issue, python was working just fine earlier (the same code). So it could possibly be something internal. For me, restarting did not work, so my next step would be to reinstall python.
The most likely cause for this is an error with the python core.